# ElectronJS - asking user for sudo permissions?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I'm trying to finish up a small Electron app that manages my files/ folders and I've found out that it requires admin permissions to do so - that means I need to use `sudo` in some of the commands that I'm trying to execute.

Is there a way I can ask user for the administrative permissions (macOS) at the launch of the app, and then use those permissions all the time?

I've tried `sudo-prompt` package, but is a pain when I need to run e.g. 3 commands in a sequence while doing other things in between - it asks for the password 3 times.

Comment: have a look at [electron-sudo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sudo)